# gem with multiple requires in gemfile

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

So I have this gem and it depends on lots of other gems. While in the gemspec it says

```
s.add_dependency "haml" ...
```

bundler does not seem to care, so I have to repeat these dependency in the Gemfile. Is there a syntax to require multiple gems? Something like that (does not work):

```
gem "so-and-so",
   :git => "some-repo",
   :require => ["this-gem", "that-gem", "and-what-not"]
```

require seems to only allow a single object

Answer (score 8):

According to [the `Gemfile` documentation](http://bundler.io/v1.1/man/gemfile.5.html) you can simply pass an array of requires.  I hit this question while researching `RSpec` like syntactical sugar for `Minitest` and noting that I'd need to:

```
require 'minitest/spec'
require 'minitest/autorun'
```

To get this to work.  I'd never tried multiple requires in a `Gemfile` before, and googling led me here to this question, and more Googling led me to the `Gemfile` docs which state:

```
REQUIRE AS (:require)
Each gem MAY specify files that should be used when autorequiring via
Bundler.require. You may pass an array with multiple files, or false
to prevent any file from being autorequired.

gem "sqlite3-ruby", :require => "sqlite3"
gem "redis", :require => ["redis/connection/hiredis", "redis"]
gem "webmock", :require => false
```

So in my own `Gemfile` I have included

```
group :test do
  gem 'minitest', require: ['minitest/autorun', 'minitest/spec']
  gem 'rack-test', require: 'rack/test'
  gem 'simplecov', require: false
end
```

Which works perfectly and allows me to write a test like

```
describe 'basic crud' do
  it 'must create a user with valid details' do
    User.transaction do
      user = User.create!(username: 'test', password: 'pass')
      user.username.must_equal 'test'
      user.destroy
    end
  end
end
```

Which I find reads nicer than `assert_equals user.username, 'test'` and gives me access to my familiar `before :each do…` and `after :all do…` prep and cleanup methods.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that Bundler looks to the gems themselves to manage their own dependencies.  The idea being that you shouldn't need syntax like this for specifying dependencies because the gem does it for you in it's `gemspec` file.  [As stated on the bundler docs](http://gembundler.com/gemfile.html), the `require` keyword is used for: 'If a gem's main file is different than the gem name, specify how to require it.'

If a gem has `s.add_dependency 'haml' ...` and it is not working then either the gem's `gempsec` file has an error, or the version of `bundler` you have has an error (or is too old to know about dependencies or something).  I would report it to the authors of the gem.

One workaround you could use till you figure out what is wrong with the gem or it's dependencies would be to [put the gem and the other required gems it uses in a group](http://gembundler.com/groups.html), and add a comment to the Gemfile mentioning why you're doing it.

Which gem are you having issues with?  If you specify a name others may be able to verify what you're experiencing or give you better help.  Also what happens when you try `gem dependency gem_name` in a shell?

Comment: is there a command for checking this with bundler? the gem comes from a private git repo and is invisible to rubygems. (which might be the cause why dependencies are not met)

Comment: Are the gems it is dependent on also private?  That is probably your problem if that is the case.  And no, I don't believe bundler has a command like that.  The appropriate command would be `gem dependency`, as that is what bundler uses.  See [rubygems docs about the dependency command](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/10#page78).  Also note that bundler only looks for gems in those specified in the `sources` directive, so if the gems it is dependent upon are not hosted on `rubygems.org`, you may need to add another source to tell it where it can find those dependencies.

Comment: I just checked, the repo isn't actually private and the gemspec is there : https://bitbucket.org/janlimpens/portfolio-engine/src/11332e9045c4/portfolio_engine.gemspec the dependencies are well known gems.

Comment: I just added this line to a blank Gemfile: `gem 'portfolio_engine', :git => 'https://bitbucket.org/janlimpens/portfolio-engine.git'`, and then executed a `bundle install`, and it installed a lot of gems that were dependencies of the bundle (including `haml`).  What gems aren't installing which you're thinking should when you try it?  What version of `bundler` are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell bundler to use your gemspec as a source for dependencies. To do that, just insert this into your `Gemfile`

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

# require this gem's dependencies
gemspec
```

Typically for a gem, this is the only contents of the `Gemfile`.